# Some Kafka Producers slower than others

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka

We are having a weird situation where some producers, running the exact same code, are slower than other producers.  After the faster producers complete their work, the slow producers remain slow.  Any suggestions?  We are running 32 kubernetes pods and each pod is running 4 producers, each producer writing to a given partition.  A given pod can have fast running producers and slow running producers.

Below is an example of the logging produced by the 4 producers on a given instance.  You can see that three of them finished in relatively the same amount of time, where as the fourth took 2 hours and 19 minutes.

```
2022-01-25 20:13:26.519  WARN 1 --- [cket-migrator-1] c.n.qube.kafka.Qube2KafkaBucketMigrator  : Completed kafka migration of 'SCRUBBED TOPIC NAME', getRecords count = 25028043, duration = 29m 16s
2022-01-25 20:13:26.520  INFO 1 --- [cket-migrator-1] c.n.qube.kafka.Qube2KafkaBucketMigrator  : I'm going to sleep (500ms), wake me when something happens
2022-01-25 20:13:26.520  INFO 1 --- [cket-migrator-1] c.n.qube.kafka.Qube2KafkaBucketMigrator  : Woke up
2022-01-25 20:14:34.268  WARN 1 --- [cket-migrator-1] c.n.qube.kafka.Qube2KafkaBucketMigrator  : Completed kafka migration of 'SCRUBBED TOPIC NAME', getRecords count = 25028043, duration = 30m 24s
2022-01-25 20:14:34.268  INFO 1 --- [cket-migrator-1] c.n.qube.kafka.Qube2KafkaBucketMigrator  : I'm going to sleep (500ms), wake me when something happens
2022-01-25 20:14:34.268  INFO 1 --- [cket-migrator-1] c.n.qube.kafka.Qube2KafkaBucketMigrator  : Woke up
2022-01-25 20:16:12.747  WARN 1 --- [cket-migrator-1] c.n.qube.kafka.Qube2KafkaBucketMigrator  : Completed kafka migration of 'SCRUBBED TOPIC NAME', getRecords count = 25028043, duration = 32m 2s
2022-01-25 20:16:12.748  INFO 1 --- [cket-migrator-1] c.n.qube.kafka.Qube2KafkaBucketMigrator  : I'm going to sleep (500ms), wake me when something happens
2022-01-25 20:16:12.748  INFO 1 --- [cket-migrator-1] c.n.qube.kafka.Qube2KafkaBucketMigrator  : Woke up
2022-01-25 22:03:54.030  WARN 1 --- [cket-migrator-1] c.n.qube.kafka.Qube2KafkaBucketMigrator  : Completed kafka migration of 'SCRUBBED TOPIC NAME', getRecords count = 25028043, duration = 2h 19m 44s
2022-01-25 22:03:54.030  INFO 1 --- [cket-migrator-1] c.n.qube.kafka.Qube2KafkaBucketMigrator  : I'm going to sleep (500ms), wake me when something happens
2022-01-25 22:03:54.030  INFO 1 --- [cket-migrator-1] c.n.qube.kafka.Qube2KafkaBucketMigrator  : Woke up
```

Comment: Not really enough information here. Are the slower producers deployed on pods that have other heavy processes running on them? Is the slow producer writing data to an unhealthy broker? Have you ran any network performance tools between the kubelet nodes and the Kafka cluster?

Comment: Are those topics the same? This could be caused by a combination of configuration on the topics + number of replicas  and client producer acks with min.in.sync replicas. Also depending on your broker topology it could be that replicas for a specific topic are being sent to a far datacenter with slow network so the acks take much longer to happen. 
Faulty Network components on the path could also cause this if they're malfunctioning.